# CardView in Android doesn't respect constraints from ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-cardview, cardview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to place a CardView within a ConstraintLayout, with a specific margin on both sides.

I set the CardView margins compared to parents, both left and right, and then set layout_width at 0dp: it will extend and take all the available space, ignoring the margin.

If instead I put the CardView inside a FrameLayout, and then apply the same exact constraints to the FrameLayout, the FrameLayout will respect them and the CardView will just fit within it (see code below).

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="...MyActivity...">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nextButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
           <...omitted...>
```

So I got it working the way I need it, but I'd like to understand why CardView doesn't take the margins into account when computing its own width, set at 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

In CardView for the setting distance from sides, you might see this example :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="186dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:constraintSet="@dimen/spacing_normal"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_double"
    app:contentPaddingTop="@dimen/spacing_double"
    app:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
```

just let me know about the result

Comment: wouldn't that only change the position within the editor? That's my understanding of the 'tools' namespace

Comment: I edited my post because I had to add sth in it, It works.

Comment: Check it, I tested it, margin left and right are working well

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me, sorry. It's the same code I put into my layout originally, plus some other stuff I don't need. However I figured out that the reason it wasn't working is that it requires layout_marginEnd and layout_marginStart instead of layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight.

Comment: It is the same code Android studio generates it's constraints

Comment: Your code is missing layout_marginEnd and layout_marginStart. That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: MarginLeft and MarginRight are enough expect you are developing your layout for right to left and left to right layouts

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasn't working is that it requires layout_marginEnd and layout_marginStart instead of layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight.

Those seem to get added by default to FrameLayout but not to CardView.

Comment: layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight are the same as start and end, so I don't see how this could have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this work without adding additional views. You just need to add the following line to you onStart or onCreateView method:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

And if you're wondering why this works, it's because DialogFragment takes the parent view of the layout (in this case your ConstraintLayout) and sets both their width and height to wrap_content. This overrides it.